# Alternative item hotkeys

Tags: dota-2

I have played just about every MOBA game to date. Using numpad 789456 simply doesn't work for item hotkeys. I like the way LoL uses 1-6 for item hotkeys, and I like the way SC/War3/DotA uses 1-6+ for control groups. I would like to use 1-6 for my items, but then that takes away my ability to use those for control groups. I know not a lot of heroes have the need for control groups, but I can't help but feel like I shouldn't change them and that I'm stuck in terms of what to do with my hotkeys. I have heard of suggestions of alt+QWEASD, but that takes away hotkeys that are used for toggling autocast.

Are there any alternatives I'm unaware of or are not remembering?

Comment: if your question was answered accordingly then mark it please. Otherwise comment on how this was not your desired answer please.
you can mark your own too.
cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you bind the item hotkeys to F1-F6, or the control groups to those and have 1-6 be for items. Of course, that depends on your overall comfort and preference, but it is a significant improvement over having to use the numpad.

The only downside is that F1-F6 are already bound to spectator actions, but those can probably be binded over to the numpad without causing you too much duress.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use, feel free to take from it as you'd like...

QWER(TG) for spells.
Z for attribute boost.
X for tower protection.
C for center on hero.
V for in-game VOIP. (` for out of game.)
B for buy.

Items:
234
D Spacebar F

1 is hero, 5 is courier.
F1-F4 for control groups.

I also plan on setting up quickbuy scripts for my number pad and/or the right side of my keyboard when the shop UI is finalized.

I find my setup extremely efficient. If you're the type with a nice mouse, you can make use of those buttons for key item slots like TP or Magic Wand. If not, DFG for the bottom row of item slots is probably more intuitive, though I have small hands and dislike the stretch to Y for "extra spell two" on some heroes. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

tbh i would set autocast to yxc (zxc for americans)
and items to alt + qwe/asd

but to answer your question: you search for alternative key to bind?
you could use a mouse with extra buttons.

on the other side you could use scripts to do 2 actions and more with 1 key.
(example: invoker can do q w e + r with only 1 key)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm fine with ZXCVBN, either permanently or until something better comes along via a patch, such as implementation of more modifier keys.